# How to add text field in contact form by admin extension in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6, contact-form

[image]I need to add field in contact form using admin extension when admin add his custom field it automatically add in contact form at frontend contact-us form

if anybody know the logic behind how to add admin added field in front end contact-us form

as i added a custom field manually my assignment is to do  using admin custom extension

i have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plese refere [this](https://magenticians.com/add-custom-field-in-magento-2-contact-page/) link**

In this way you can get your solution if any issue feel free to comment

If helped please Accept Answer
Thanks

Comment: Thanks but i did that and add  screenshot. need to do using admin custom extension

Comment: what do u mean by admin custom extension

Comment: yes when admin add a field (input box textarea,multiselect,dropdown) it automatically add in frontend contact-us form and send all data using mail template

Comment: ok let me see....

Comment: did my answer helped